# How to kick out a tuple with half of the same contraint Key in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have to make a rooms without TVs(="Fernseher) which are patient room(=Patientenzimmer) in the Neurology, but we have a room which have a TV(=Fernseher) and a Bed(=Krankenbett), so it shows us the room in the select table, which it should not because it also have a TV.

"first table" https://ibb.co/x768479

"second table" https://ibb.co/7v8VXSG

"wrong select" https://ibb.co/YL015sc

```
SELECT r.pkRaum AS Raumnummer
FROM raum_hat_ausstattung AS a, raum as r
WHERE r.pkraum = a.fkraum
    AND a.fkAusstattung NOT LIKE "Fernseher" 
    AND r.fkTyp LIKE "Patientenzimmer" 
    AND r.fkAbteilung LIKE "Neurologie"

ORDER BY  a.fkRaum asc;
```

Comment: See [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query), we can't easy reproduce images..

Comment: Also i advice to better normalise are you table have repeating values all over it.. As it prevent typing errors while inserting, better diskspace usage..